# virsh adding x2apic, cache specific options to kvm config

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, virsh

Anybody know the syntax how to add +x2apic to the virtual machines xml files when I edit them with "virsh edit vm"?

From the command line it would be starting with this flag:

```
qemu -cpu $MODEL,+x2apic ...
```

My other question is how to add the cache=none into the disk section:

Guest Caching Mode

 cache = writethough is the default & provides data integrity in all cases (disk cache not exposed to guest)

 cache = writethrough is great for read-intensive workloads (host’s page cache enabled)

 cache = none is great for write-intensive workloads or workloads involving NFS remote storage (host’s page cache disable and
disk write cache enabled)

Thanks

Comment: Did you try reading the [documentation](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html)?

Answer (score 0):

As of qemu 2.0.0 any x86 KVM VM will have x2apic automatically enabled, so there's no explicit need to opt in. From qemu.git:
commit ef02ef5f4536dba090b12360a6c862ef0e57e3bc
Author: Eduardo Habkost 
Date:   Wed Feb 19 11:58:12 2014 -0300

```
target-i386: Enable x2apic by default on KVM
```